# XenApp on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, xenapp

I would like to deploy an Application using XenApp on a linux server.  Is it possible to do this via virtual box on a remote linux machine?

So far I have installed virtual box on a centos based linux machine.
I installed a Windows 2008 R2 Server virtual machine.
I then tried to install XenApp on the windows 2008 server.
After updating the windows 2008 server with the latest stuff and adding .net 3.5 and sql server express I got XenApp installed.

I am stuck at the point of deploying the Single Sign-On service.  It wants a "UNC path to the central store of the citricl signle sign on".  Does anyone know how to set that up?

I don't have a domain controller, nor do I have active directory installed.  Do I need those things?  I was really hoping to avoid that.

What does XenApp require?  I kind of figured it would be plug and play but it doesn't appear that way and the installation instructions are very vague about system requirements.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Single Sign-On is not required for XenApp.

[From the documentation](http://support.citrix.com/proddocs/topic/technologies/pm-library-wrapper.html)

> Citrix Single Sign-on (formerly Citrix Password Manager) provides password security and single sign-on access to Windows, Web, and terminal emulator applications running in the Citrix environment as well as applications running on the desktop. Users authenticate once and Single Sign-on does the rest, automatically logging on to password-protected information systems, enforcing password policies, monitoring all password-related events, and even automating user tasks, including password changes.

**Basically:** SSO needs a place to put the Central Password Store.

Just give it a path to a network share that all XenApp servers can access.  If you're using a single machine; create a local network share and point to it using UNC

> \\localhost\SSO_Store